# What's the easiest way to use stack, queue and linked list in C++ in Xcode on the Mac?

Tags: c++, stl, std

My professor told me about STL (he doesn't use a Mac currently). With some googling, I found that STL has been deprecated for years. What's the current way to do this most easily?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between ["STL"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/info) and the C++ standard library, the latter of which comes with any C++ compiler and _does_ have [`stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), [`queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), [`list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), and [`forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list).

Comment: "Deprecated for years?"  What are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

The STL is the precursor to certain parts of the standard library (STD). Sometimes the term is used to refer to those parts.

To use stack, `#include <stack>`. There's also `<list>` and `<queue>`, and many others.

Here is a good reference site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/

And as always, a good book: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

You are just reading [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library), which states that `#include <*.h>` (old C libraries) have been deprecated.